# How to use directive for model input?

Tags: angularjs

I have model `node`:

```
{"id":"593d408cb25f42a812000042","prefix":"array_simple",
 "title":"Array_simple","type":"3","value":["A","B","C"],"nodes":[]}
```

In this obejct there is field value with value as array:

```
"value":["A","B","C"]
```

How to use directive to display inputs for each values in array and bind this to model back after changes?

I tried to write directive:

```
.directive('inputArray', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },

        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element) {

                scope.inputs = [];

                if (angular.isArray(scope.data.value)) {
                    angular.forEach(scope.data.value, function (value) {
                        scope.inputs.push({"type": scope.data.type, "value": value});
                    });

                } else {
                    scope.inputs.push({"type": scope.data.type, "value": scope.data.value});
                }
            }
        },
        template: `<input ng-repeat="value in inputs track by $index" 
                     ng-model="node.value"
                     ng-hide="value.type=='2' || value.type=='6'" 
                     type="text" value="$$value.value$$">`,
        replace: true
    }
})
```

But it does not change model back after changes.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to implement a directive, get something working with just template and controller:

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <div ng-init='data = {"id":"593d408cb25f42a812000042","prefix":"array_simple",
 "title":"Array_simple","type":"3","value":["A","B","C"],"nodes":[]}'>
    </div>

    <div  ng-repeat="item in data.value track by $index">
      <input ng-model="data.value[$index]" type="text" />
    </div>

    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <p>{{data.value}}</p>
  </body>
```

Instead of copying data to a new data model, use the data model directly using `$index` and [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), `data.value[$index]`.